# Delayed choice quantum eraser : help

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Is this right:

We can observe the cloth pattern BEFORE we decide whether to quantum erase or not (i.e., say the photons must travel an hour before they hit the beam splitters that erase the path information). In this case, since we have already observed the cloth, we know whether or not the wave function collapsed and can use the information to choose to erase or not erase, breaking down this whole system, it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you'll always get a smear, not the interference(cloth?) pattern; the interference pattern only emerges after correlating information from both detectors at sublight speeds.
This video explains it really well I think, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ORLN_KwAgs